# React-Intl plural message getting errors

Tags: react-intl, pluralize

The message is `Check out {count, plural, one {# item}, other {# items}}`.

I'm invoking it with:

```
<FormattedMessage id="button.message" values={{ count: cartItemsCount }} />
```

But I'm getting these errors:

```
[React Intl] Error formatting message: "button.message" for locale: "en"
SyntaxError: Expected "{" but "o" found.
```

and

```
[React Intl] Cannot format message: "button.message", using message source as fallback.
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ICU message is invalid: `Check out {count, plural, one {# item} other {# items}}` (no `,` between `one` & `other`

Comment: are you saying it should, or shouldn't, have a comma? (I'd test it directly, but have moved on since I asked the question)

Comment: It should not have `,`